# How can I Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I use Regex.Replace to achieve the flowing:
Given the input string:

```
"DV_DHW dv_DWH dv_dwh Dv_Dwh some more text dv_dwhtest"
```

I want to change it to :

```
"Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW  some more text dv_dwhtest"
```

I tried this:

```
Regex.Replace("Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW  some more text dv_dwhtest", "DV_DHW", "Test_DV_DHW", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But it replace just the first instance of DV_DHW (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input contains "DV_DHW" and "DV_DWH". Those aren't the same string. Notice that the first is D-H-W, where "H" is before "W", and the second has "W" before "H."

Since they're not the same, only the first occurrence of "DV_DHW" gets replaced. The correct output is:

> Test_DV_DHW dv_DWH dv_dwh Dv_Dwh some more text dv_dwhtest

If your intention was to replace both of the strings, expect the last one since it isn't a whole word, you could use this pattern: `@"\bDV_D(?:HW|WH)\b"`

The `\b` metacharacter matches a word-boundary and then the pattern uses `(?:...)` for a non-capturing group that will match either "HW" or "WH" text.

The above pattern would produce this output:

> Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW Test_DV_DHW some more text
>   dv_dwhtest

Notice that the last word, "dv_dwhtest," hasn't been modified since the "dv_dwh" wasn't a whole word and was a part of a word instead.